# Is mysqli_autocommit, mysqli_commit and mysqli_rollback are synchronous?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I mean if I create a dynamic webpage with php. If user enter "1", multiple queries will run if user enter "0", only single query will run. For multiple queries I need to use autocommit, rollback and commit so that if one query fails all queries will rollback. And for single query I don't need those functions.

My question is that if user1 from a pc entered "1" and user2 from other pc entered "0". Since user1 entered "1", autocommit is going to be false. Does that effect user2?

Same for rollback and commit. If user1 queries failed it calls for rollback does it effect user2 query?

Please help me I'm new to this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each connection is treated as a separate entity or session, no matter if it's the same login information or different mysql users. When you start a transaction with begin_transaction, it sets the transaction mode for that session only. User1 and User2, despite logging in with the same information via PHP, are treated as separate sessions.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Comment: That goes same for mysqli_autocommit(), mysqli_commit and mysqli_rollback right? I mean that doesn't permanently change autocommit of database to false right

Comment: Correct, and actually goes for any mysqli/PDO command, and even straight mysql connections. For instance, I have a script that creates temporary tables, with the name based on the flag that I pass to the script. So if I start a script at the same time with 2 different flags, the script running with flag1 cannot access the temporary tables created by the script running with flag2.

Comment: A small doubt, at the end there will be two tables created right?

Comment: Yes, but they're temporary tables. They only exist as long as the session exists, to the session that created it. Once the session ends, the temporary tables disappear.